# Wordpress tax_query based on custom taxonomy not showing any result

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have this query based on WordPress docs, but no result. If I remove the tax_query it gives all publish posts, but when I add it, it displays no result.

I have checked the database and I'm sure there is post attached to the wp_term_taxonomy so I'm not sure why it doesn't display results.

What I am doing here, I get all custom taxonomy type then loop through it to get all posts related to it.

```
$event_terms = get_terms(
    'event_type',
    array(
        'orderby'=>'name',
        'hide_empty'=>true
    )
);

if(!empty($event_terms) && !is_wp_error($event_terms)){
    foreach($event_terms as $event_term){
        // code for each event term
        $args = array(
            'status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $event_term->slug,
                ),
            ),
        );

         $loop = new WP_Query($args);
         if($loop->have_posts()) {

            echo '<h2>'.$event_term->name.'</h2>';

            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
            endwhile;
         }

    // this displays all taxonomy terms
    echo $event_term->name."-".$event_term->term_taxonomy_id."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: you codes seems okey. May be the issue is in its executions, means when your codes is executed, may be the taxonomy `event_type` is not initialised. Try to run your above codes in `wp` hook or any others that fire after taxonomy initialised.

Comment: @itzmekhokan do you know a hook the suited this?

Comment: I already mentioned this in above. You can use `wp` hook like  `add_action( 'wp', 'your_callback' );`

Comment: I mean what kind of hook, I've been using add_action btw, using wp_loaded hooks, still not getting. I tested it with category taxonomy it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your text query like this and try:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
       'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => $event_term->slug
    )
  )
) );
$count = $the_query->found_posts;
```

I hope this is helps you.